# On the preimage of maximal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $\varphi:R\to S$ be a map of commutative rings. It is well known that if $M$ is maximal in $S$ then the preimage $\varphi^{-1}(M)$ need not be maximal in $R$ (consider $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}$). There are however special cases such as the following:

> 1. If $\varphi$ is surjective, then $\varphi^{-1}(M)$ is maximal in $R$.
> 2. If $R$ and $S$ are algebras over a field $K$, and $S$ is finitely generated and $\varphi$ is a map of $K$-algebras, then $\varphi^{-1}(M)$ is maximal in $R$.

**Question:** How much can be said about the converse? Namely, if $\varphi$ satisfies the property that $\varphi^{-1}(M)$ is maximal in $R$ for every maximal in $S$, what can be said about $R$, $S$ and $\varphi$? I am assuming not much, so can we make additional assumptions to make this question interesting? Any references are welcome.

Comment: Here are some low hanging ideas. Your special cases can be generalized to: when $\varphi$ is integral, and when it is a map of $K$-algebras such that “maximal residue fields” of $S$ are algebraic over $K$ (so that any $K$-integral domains contained in them are finite extensions of $K$) – including also $S$ being an affinoid algebra over a complete valued field. But it’s hard to say anything more specific… we can of course assume $S$ local, but it’s not easy to say what kind of property would correspond to “the inverse image by a map into $S$ of the maximal ideal is maximal”.